# Why does Delphi XE7 IDE hangs and fails on out of memory exception?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-ide

I'm using Delphi XE7 IDE and it quite frequently hangs, starts to consume many system resources and fails on exceptions like:

- system out of memory --> ([dcc32 Fatal Error] F2046 Out of memory)
- external exceptions
- [MSBuild Error] The "DependencyCheck" task failed unexpectedly.
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Out of memory
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.IBDSHostObject.GetFileTime(String filename)
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.DependencyCheck.DoGetFileTime(String filename)
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.DependencyCheck.GetFileNameTime(String filename)
  at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.DependencyCheck.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)

What is the reason for third exception?

What can I do to make it stable ?

Comment: `What can be done?` Showing some code you have problems with would be helpful.

Comment: This problem is not related to specific project.When i start compiling the project, the ide hangs and throws system out of memory exception.It is occupying almost 800mb of cpu memory. Is there any tool for this problem?

Comment: Try using the IDEFixPackRegXE7.exe add on with DelphiXE7.

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

Comment: Thanks!! Now i am able to compile without the exceptions

Comment: Delphi XE7 is a "train wreck" as people from EurekaLog put it. We pay lots of money to Embarcadero yet we have to rely on people as Andy (who don't get a dime) to have Delphi fixed. http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

Comment: @Altar Thanks for your input!! But i am still using Delphi XE7. Fix pack provided by Andy is for XE7 (UP1) version. Do you recommend me to update to XE7 (UP1) version?

Comment: @kvsbhavani-I don't really think there is a difference between XE7 and XE7 Update 1. I doubt they fixed many bugs. I have Update 1 but Delphi is still slower than a snail and crashes all the time. Delphi XE was much more stable than XE7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [Quality embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9568)

The fequently 'out of memory' in XE7 problem.
Some solution to decrease 'out of memory'

1. Add  DDevExtensions and IDEFixPack

   DDevExtensions Options --> Compilations --> Check 'Release compiler unit cache of other projects before compiling'
2. Use the external MSBuild addresses Here is how:

   Project | Options | Delphi Compiler, set Use MSBuild externally to compile

   Project | Options | Delphi Compiler | Compiling | Debugging, set Use debug .dcus to False

   Project | Options | Delphi Compiler | Linking, set Include remote debug symbols to True
3. renaming Delphi's c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\Borland.Studio.Delphi.DLL,   the IDE will remain stable much longer and you are able to get some work done!! Note the IDE will give you an error when starting up about this DLL being missing. This appears to prevent a lot of the needless churning and burning the IDE was doing that was consuming memory and machine cycles
4. try starting the IDE with the -noparser option... "BDS.EXE -noparser" this will switch the parser off for the structure pane

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!! I  already tried 2nd option.Still it was throwing error.Now i installed idefixpack and it's working fine

Comment: Does the `-noparser` option work? And which versions support it? [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options) makes no mention of it.

Comment: I have the same problem ... IDE compiles fine, than crashs and takes hours to open some Units.
I'll try these steps.

Comment: @CraigYoung Fix Pack will work much better. "noparser" option did work for me but only for some time. So i downloaded idefixpack. You can even try to increase your RAM space.